# Update props of specific component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I've got an array full of rooms:

```js
const room = (<Room
    points={points}
    scene={this.scene}
    key={this.rooms.length}
    keyV={this.rooms.length}
    />)

this.rooms.push(room);
```

Now for example I got 3 rooms each with their own initial points:
Room 1 : points={a,b,c}
Room 2 : points={d,e,f}
Room 3 : points={g,h,i}

Now I want to update the points of room 2 to {d,e,f,x} (this.points). I know this can be done with:

```
this.setState({points: this.points})
```

But this updates the points of all the rooms. I want to only update room 2 with new points. How can this be achieved?

**Update:**
I create a room when I draw two lines. Now when I draw the third line the existing room needs to be updated with an extra point.

Comment: on what action or event do you want to update ?

Comment: When I draw a new wallI I check if there is an already existing room to which I can add this wall. So if there is I want to update this room with an extra point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `setState`, make sure you update the actual rooms.
For instance, when you are creating `Room` component, you can have some `index` or some identifier to identity which `Room` you want to update.

```
<Room points={...} onUpdate={()=>{this.onUpdate(someId)}}
```

Your `onUpdate` fn could be like

```
onUpdate(RoomIdToUpdate) {
  let updatedRooms = this.rooms.map((room) => {
    if(room.id === RoomIdToUpdate) {
      return Object.assign({}, room, {
        points: [...yourUpdatedPointsArray]
      })
    }
    return room;
  })
}
```

Then you can `set state`

```
this.setState({
  rooms: updatedRooms
})
```

Hope this helps.

**Update:**

Have a look at the below sample for reference. 
Check the `componentWillReceiveProps()` fn and my comments for better understanding

```js
// componentWillReceiveProps will be called as Room component will receive new props.
class Room extends React.Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log(nextProps) //new props
    console.log(this.props) //old props
  }
  
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
         {this.props.data.roomNo}
         <button onClick={this.props.updateRoom}> Update Room</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
  
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      roomsData: [
        {
          points: [1,2],
          roomNo: 1
        },
        {
          points: [3,4],
          roomNo: 2
        },
        {
          points: [5,6],
          roomNo: 3
        }
      ]
    };
    this.updateRoom = this.updateRoom.bind(this);
  }
  
  updateRoom(roomNoToUpdate) {
    let newPoints = [2,3,4,5];
    let updatedRoomsData =  this.state.roomsData.map((data) => {
      if(data.roomNo === roomNoToUpdate) {
        return Object.assign({}, data, {
          points: [...newPoints]
        })
      } else {
        return data
      }
    })

    this.setState({ roomsData: updatedRoomsData });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.roomsData.map((data, index) => {
            return <Room key={index} data={data} 
                    updateRoom={() => this.updateRoom(data.roomNo)}
                  />
          })
        }
        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: So if I just want to update the points I can call this:
Object.assign({}, this.rooms[1], { points: this.points}) ?

Comment: If number of rooms are fixed, and you don't want it to be dynamically updated based on some identifier, then yes you call as above

Comment: When you call this Object.assign(), componentWillReceiveProps() is not called in this component. So how do I check in the component if the props are updated

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps() will be called when new props are received by the component.  In your case if you have a Room component, when points are changed, the componentWillReceiveProps() in Room component will be called.

Comment: Well I tested it and componentWillReceiveProps() is not called when I use Object.assign()

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just continuously run an update in my room component. And I check in this update if the props have been changed